# force redirect to new browser nodejs function

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I found an npm package that works like a charm... sort of. it can force redirect to a browser when necessary. But the problem is, I have some crazy code with sso (azuread) implemented. for some reason, with the following code below, it redirects to the new browser but in a continuous loop until my computer shuts down...

```
  app.get('/login',
  passport.authenticate('saml', { failureRedirect: '/', failureFlash: true }),
  function(req, res) {
      console.log("working okay /login")
    console.log("inside azuread /login get passport saml")
     res.render('login.ejs')
  });

  function ensureAuth(req, res, next) {
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
       return next();
    } else {
        openBrowser();
        res.redirect("/login")
    }
}

  app.get('/login/:pagename?', ensureAuth, pagename)
  app.get('/:pagename?', ensureAuth, pagename)




 function openBrowser() {
    opn('http://localhost:3333', {app: 'safari'})
}



   function pagename(req, res) {
       //this runs all my code...
}
```

not sure why it would be opening new tabs in a continuous loop like this. please help :(

Comment: which 'npm' package are you using?

Comment: I used npm install opn